# How to define custom configuration variables in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, railtie

I was wondering how to add custom configuration variables to a Rails application and how to access them in the controller?

Secondly, I was planning to have S3 support for uploads in my application, if I wanted to add a yaml file with the S3 access, secret key, how do I initialize it in my Rails App and how do I access the values that I have defined in that config file.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app

Comment: Slightly related: Don't forget to restart the server when adding new configuration variables.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

**Update 1**

Very recommended: I'm going with [Rails Config](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config) gem nowadays for the fine grained control it provides.

**Update2**

If you want a quick solution, then check [Jack Pratt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5053882/1207687) below.

**Although my original answer below still works, this answer is now outdated. I recommend looking at updates 1 and 2.**

*Original Answer:*

For a quick solution, watching the "YAML Configuration File" [screen cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file) by Ryan Bates should be very helpful.

In summary:

```
# config/initializers/load_config.rb
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]

# application.rb
if APP_CONFIG['perform_authentication']
  # Do stuff
end
```

Comment: This answer is out-dated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450285/how-to-define-custom-configuration-variables-in-rails/5053882#5053882 below

Comment: @matt: Is it outdated because Rails 3 has been released, or because *everyone* is now on Rails 3, or ...?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the outdated. I hate that about Rails -- code from 1 year ago is too old.

Comment: For anyone wanting to use the YAML method in Rails 3+, you'll have to replace `RAILS_ENV` with `Rails.env` and `RAILS_ROOT` with `Rails.root`.

Comment: I tried rails_config. In the documentation they instruct me to register RailsConfig in my app.rb. I assume that app.rb = config/application.rb. But where in the application.rb should I put the register RailsConfig line?

Answer (score 386):

In Rails 3, Application specific custom configuration data can be placed in the application configuration object. The configuration can be assigned in the initialization files or the environment files -- say for a given application `MyApp`:

```
MyApp::Application.config.custom_config_variable = :my_config_setting
```

or

```
Rails.configuration.custom_config_variable = :my_config_setting
```

To read the setting, simply call the configuration variable without setting it:

```
Rails.configuration.custom_config_variable
=> :my_config_setting
```

**UPDATE Rails 4**

In Rails 4 there a new way for this => http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually work. I'm unable to reference the variable anywhere else in the application. There's also no mention of being able to do it this way here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: It works for me. I put my environment specific configuration settings in environments/{environment}.rb, e.g., environments/development.rb. Make sure you restart your server after modifying. There may be more elegant techniques, but I'm upgrading an existing app which previously used ENV['XXX'] in the same file, and since I want to limit the amount of refactoring during the upgrade, this worked out well.

Comment: This is assignment but how do you access this value then?

Comment: If you look in the application.rb of a rails 3.x app it sais "Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers" as per this answer. There is plenty of documentation on how to access the variable (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html). e.g. in a file called some_variables.rb in the initializers folder place the variable as described above (replacing MyApp with the name of your app) then when you want to use it just call config.custom_config_variable You can of course use whatever variable name you like. @Jack Pratt you could edit a more complete answer?

Comment: I'm on Rails 3.0.4 and could access the config variable only by doing: Rails.application.config.custom_config_variable.

Comment: Dude, simple:

Path:

`config/environments/production.rb`

Config:

`config.whatever = false`

Access it anywhere:

`Rails.configuration.whatever`

Comment: Is it possible to use this to set different values in different environments? I want to configure a variable that has different values in dev and prod.

Comment: Beware that if you set something only in production, and try to access it in another environment, it would complain `undefined method`.

Comment: What so cool about this bulky solution? A couple of people will die on Earth while you type `Rails.configuration.whatever`. Besides, it's not suitable when you need to keep **sensitive data**, e.g. an app email password, _out_ of the **scm**.

Comment: Yeah as @lulalala has mentioned, it gives an error if the value isn't defined. I want to assume a value if it isn't defined... is this possible?

Comment: Is there a way to check if a config name has been defined? i.e. if `Rails.configuration.custom_config_variable` is conditionally set, and then later it is used, but get `undefined method`.

Comment: @msanjay, try `Rails.config.my_variable ||= 'default value'`. That overrides the variable with 'default value' if it's not defined, but leaves it alone otherwise.

Comment: this does not work for me on rails 3.2.11, i get a 'rails could not start: undefined method error' in the `development.rb` config file, makes sense as I am trying to write to a field that does not exist! how could this ever work?

Comment: @Tilo, lynks: Use this answer for > Rails 3.2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800028/rails-3-setting-custom-environment-variables

Comment: This may be more of the ruby question. How MyApp::Application.config.custom_config_variable work. I don't think there is a custom_config_variable setter or getter in the config(Rails::Application::Configuration) object. How does this work from ruby perspective object point of view ?.

Comment: This is not working in Rails 4.1 I get errors "...`method_missing': undefined method `store' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f9f735b7240>..." if I try to add a variable like config.store.works

Comment: @Spundun I had the same problem, this will do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18768914/498238

Comment: Note that `x` part is probably there for namespacing and *must be* included when entering custom config. It's an object of type [`Rails::Application::Configuration::Custom`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.1/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L191).

Comment: As @HalilÖzgür  pointed out, `x` is for namespacing, so it could assign a custom config object. Otherwise it will just to be method missing, then dynamically create attributes, which could be bad.

Answer (score 70):

In Rails 3.0.5, the following approach worked for me:

In `config/environments/development.rb`, write

```
config.custom_config_key = :config_value
```

The value `custom_config_key` can then be referenced from other files using

```
Rails.application.config.custom_config_key
```

Comment: Beware that if you set something only in production, and try to access it in another environment, it would complain `undefined method`.

Comment: I Tried this in rails 4.1 and I'm getting errors, "...`method_missing': undefined method `store' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f9f735b7240>...". I was trying to add "config.store.works" config variable.

Comment: @Spundun You're getting that error, because Rails doesn't know what `store` is.  In order to use the method in this answer, you can either rename your variable `store_works`, or create a `config.store` block with `works` defined therein.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually figured that out. That these are nested hashes so I have to initialize empty hashes recursively if I'm to use dots in my config names.

Answer (score 34):

## In Rails 4

Assuming you put your custom variables into a yaml file:

```
# config/acme.yml
development:
  :api_user: 'joe'
  :api_pass: 's4cret'
  :timeout: 20
```

Create an initializer to load them:

```
# config/initializers/acme.rb
acme_config = Rails.application.config_for :acme

Rails.application.configure do
  config.acme = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
  config.acme.api_user = acme_config[:api_user]
  config.acme.api_pass = acme_config[:api_pass]
  config.acme.timeout  = acme_config[:timeout]
end
```

Now anywhere in your app you can access these values like so:

```
Rails.configuration.acme.api_user
```

It is convenient that `Rails.application.config_for :acme` will load your `acme.yml` and use the correct environment.

Answer (score 31):

This works in rails 3.1:

**in config/environment.rb    (or in config/environments/.. to target a specific environment)  :**

```
YourApp::Application.config.yourKey = 'foo'
```

This will be accessible in controller or views like this:

```
YourApp::Application.config.yourKey
```

*(YourApp should be replaced by your application name.)*

**Note**: It's Ruby code, so if you have a lot of config keys, you can do this :

in config/environment.rb :

```
YourApp::Application.configure do
  config.something = foo
  config.....
  config....
  .
  config....
end
```

Comment: camelCase :o use snake_case!

Answer (score 24):

**Since Rails 4.2, without additional gems,** you can load *config/hi.yml* simply by using `Rails.application.config_for :hi`.

**For example:**

1. `touch config/passwords.yml`

   ```
       #config/passwords.yml
       development:
         username: 'a'
         password: 'b'
       production:
         username: 'aa'
         password: 'bb'
   ```

2. `touch config/initializers/constants.rb`

   ```
   #config/initializers/constants.rb
   AUTHENTICATION = Rails.application.config_for :passwords
   ```

3. and now you can use `AUTHENTICATION` constant everywhere in your application:

   ```
   #rails c production
   :001> AUTHENTICATION['username'] => 'aa'
   ```
4. then add *passwords.yml* to *.gitignore*: `echo /config/passwords.yml >> .gitignore`, create an example file for your comfort `cp /config/passwords.yml /config/passwords.example.yml` and then just edit your example file in your production console with actual production values.

Answer (score 20):

**Rails 6 and 7**

Many outdated answers, so adding one that is specific to Rails 6.

Application specific configuration goes in initializer files. Details are here: [edge guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files)

Example:

## config/initializers/foo.rb

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.test_val = 'foo'
  end
end
```

Alternatively:

```
Rails.application.config.test_val = 'foo'
```

This can now be accessed as:

```
Rails.configuration.test_val
```

Many more possibilities.
[edge guides #custom-configuration](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration)

ex, you can also set up nested namespace configurations:

```
config.x.payment_processing.schedule = :daily
config.x.payment_processing.retries  = 3
config.super_debugger = true
```

or use config_for to load entire custom config files:

## config/payment.yml

```
production:
  environment: production
  merchant_id: production_merchant_id
  public_key:  production_public_key
  private_key: production_private_key

development:
  environment: sandbox
  merchant_id: development_merchant_id
  public_key:  development_public_key
  private_key: development_private_key
```

Then load it with:

## config/initializers/load_payment.rb

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.payment = config_for(:payment)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14):

I just wanted to update this for the latest cool stuff in Rails 4.2, you can now do this inside any of your `config/**/*.rb` files:

```
config.x.whatever.you.want = 42
```

...and this will be available in your app as:

```
Rails.configuration.x.whatever.you.want
```

See more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration

Answer (score 8):

Check out this neat gem doing exactly that:
https://github.com/mislav/choices

This way your sensitive data won't be exposed in open source projects

Answer (score 4):

I created a simple plugin for YAML settings:  [Yettings](https://github.com/cowboycoded/yettings)

It works in a similar fashion to the code in khelll's answer, but you only need to add this YAML configuration file:

```
app/config/yetting.yml
```

The plugin dynamically creates a class that allows you to access the YML settings as class methods in your app like so:

```
Yetting.your_setting
```

Also, if you want to use multiple settings files with unique names, you can place them in a subdirectory inside app/config like this:

```
app/config/yettings/first.yml
app/config/yettings/second.yml
```

Then you can access the values like this:

```
FirstYetting.your_setting
SecondYetting.your_setting
```

It also provides you with default settings that can be overridden per environment.  You can also use erb inside the yml file.

Comment: The official repo is now at: https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/yettings (SO reviewer rejected my edit saying it is too minor)

Answer (score 4):

I really like the [settingslogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic) gem. Very easy to set up and use.

https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic

Comment: Loving this so far. Putting your settings object at app/models/settings.rb gets you reloading in dev mode too. Win!

Answer (score 4):

If you use Heroku or otherwise have need to keep your application settings as environment variables, the [figaro](http://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use [rails-settings](http://github.com/Squeegy/rails-settings) for global configuration values that need to be changeable via web interface.

Comment: I dint wanna use additional plugins etc, as I am learning rails, so the best way to do it would be without any plugins.

Comment: Note this uses database to store configurations, which maybe too heavy for some people.

Answer (score 2):

Something we've starting doing at work is the [ActiveSupport Ordered Hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/OrderedOptions.html)

Which allows you to define your configuration cleanly inside the environment files e.g.

```
config.service = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
config.service.api_key = ENV['SERVICE_API_KEY']
config.service.shared_secret = ENV['SERVICE_SHARED_SECRET']
```

Answer (score -6):

I would suggest good approach how to deal with configuration in your application at all. There are three basic rules:

- change your configuration not a code;
- use configurations over conditions;
- write code that means something.

To have more detailed overview follow this link: [Rails configuration in the proper way](http://railsware.com/blog/2013/10/16/rails-configuration-in-the-proper-way/)