# Rails 3 - how to use an environment-specific configuration in haml partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Following the [answer on How to define custom configuration variables in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5053882/305019), I am trying to set up a configuration settings for different environments in `config/environments/{env}.rb`

e.g. in `development.rb` I set

`config.elvis = 'alive'`

and then in my haml template I can use this variable, e.g.

`Elvis is #{Rails.configuration.elvis}`.

However, when I want to wrap this in a condition:

```
- if Rails.configuration.elvis
  <p>Elvis is #{Rails.configuration.elvis}</p>
```

it also works, but if the configuration isn't set, it throws a `undefined method` error.

If I try instead:

```
- if defined? Rails.configuration.elvis
  <p>Elvis is #{Rails.configuration.elvis}</p>
```

it seems to always evaluate as false, even with the configuration defined.

Still very new to rails/ruby, so apologies if it's a very dumb question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F):

```
- if Rails.configuration.respond_to?(:elvis)
  <p>Elvis is #{Rails.configuration.elvis}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the super-fast response! Worked like a charm (will mark as answered in 7 minutes or so when I'm allowed...)