# Rails: Where to define facebook app id so that it is available to the devise initializer and the controllers.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, global-variables, yaml, omniauth

I am trying to set the fb app id (used by omniauth) so that its global to devise initialiser and to the controllers.

**MORE INFO**

I need it in devise initialiser (config/initializer/devise.rb) so that I can set
config.omniauth :facebook, fb_app_id, fb_app_secret

**Attempted Solution**

I tried adding this info into a yml file ( http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file ), however, looks like the yml hash is set for the controllers, but I can not use it for the devise initialiser.

```
/home/ubuntu/myapp/config/initializers/devise.rb:215:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant APP_CONFIG (NameError)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who are interested, I ended up writing up the variables in config/environments/production.rb & config/environments/development.rb

You can set global variables by adding:

```
config.fb_app_id = 23839282 
config.fb_app_secret = aj32j32j4jk
```

(set the appropriate one in production.rb or development.rb)

These can then be used in initialisers, and also in my actual application's views, controllers, etc.

```
Rails.configuration.fb_app_id
Rails.configuration.fb_app_secret
```

Read the second answer in: 
[How to define custom configuration variables in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450285/how-to-define-custom-configuration-variables-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

I do this by adding an initializer (called `env.rb`) that set up the various env vars I need (as `ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID']`, for instance).

Comment: interesting - however, these environment variables cannot distinguish whether I am on development or production mode ...

Comment: you could set them in your production server manually (eg. using `export FACEBOOK_APP_ID=...`, and in the initializer, instead of using `=`, you could use `||=`

Comment: hmm... is there any way of loading it through yml - im trying to get something similar to what is described in the railcast

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I came to a different solution. I passed ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'] into CONFIG.OMNIAUTH from within devise.rb. Then I add the environment variable (~/.bash_profile) or heroku config:add FACEBOOK_APP_ID. This allows me to install to new environments and regenerate APPIDs without pushing new code.