# RSpec: How to test file parser

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, file-io

I'm new to both ruby and rspec and I'm wondering how to test a class that must parse a file.  Here is the function I plan to test:

```
def self.get_description(event_code)
  # search through a file for the event_code and return
  # the associated description field
end
```

In production I'll hard code the file's path.  How should I control the file contents from rspec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a few specs which parse [`Tempfiles` that you create](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) containing valid and invalid input and ensure that the parse function returns the expected results (or exceptions).

Comment: Thanks for posting that link.  So what is the best way to have my class open the temp file while it's being tested, but open the actual file while running?

Comment: You'll need to parameterize the name of the file that gets parsed so that it can be overridden per environment; consider this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450285/how-to-define-custom-configuration-variables-in-rails