# Scoped configuration variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using my `config/environments/<env>.rb` files to set custom configuration variables (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5053882/483520). For example, I might set the following:

```
config.google_analytics_on = false #or true, in a production environment
config.google_analytics_account = "<account-string>"
```

It would be nice to be able to do:

```
config.google_analytics.on = false
config.google_analytics.account = "<account-string>"
```

so that all my google_analytics variables would be under that scope. However, rails complains about `config.google_analytics` not being defined. How do I create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
opts = {on: false, account: "<account-string>"}
config.google_analytics = OpenStruct.new(opts)
```

Comment: Can I do something with a syntax more like:
`config.google_analytics = OpenStruct.new`
`config.google_analytics.on = false`
`config.google_analytics.account = "<account-string>"` EDIT: Indeed: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html