# How do I set different api keys for my development and production environments in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment

I am doing some development involving the Stripe API. In my development environment I am using my stripe test key. In production I am using the real api key so that I can process real transactions of course.

I am currently just changing out the test api key immediately before I deploy to my production environment; this does not feel very good. A strategy that I am pretty sure would work is to just make a development branch with a gitignore (ignoring my initializer that loads the api key) and then just merging it with the master branch before I deploy; this way the api keys would always be correct in their respective environments. I don't really like this approach though.  Is there some sort of way to configure these api keys somewhere so that the app just knows which one to use when in dev/prod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it :

In config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
if(Rails.env == 'development' || Rails.env == 'staging')
  Stripe.api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
elsif(Rails.env == 'production')
  Stripe.api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
end
```

Comment: That works, but it would not be following the best practices: what happens when you commit your code to a shared repo? The production keys would become available to your entire team. Production keys should be set in the environment (ENV).

Answer (score 9):

In rails 4.1 we have the `config/secrets.yml` file so you can set the api keys there like so:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 'xxx'
  publishable_key: xxx
  secret_key: xxx
production:
  secret_key_base: 'xxx'
  publishable_key: xxx
  secret_key: xxx
```

And in your stripe.rb file you can do this:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => Rails.application.secrets.publishable_key,
  :secret_key      => Rails.application.secrets.secret_key
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using [yetting](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/yettings).

Though adding API keys in to the environments files gets the job done, adding them to a seperate file seems a whole lot of a cleaner and abstracted way to me.

Once the gem is installed. you can make a yetting.yml file in the config directory.

```
development:
  facebook_app_id: xxxxxx
staging:
  facebook_app_id: xxxxxx
production:
  facebook_app_id: xxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this cat.

Quick and simple, look at `Rails.env`.

It will return the environment the server is running in.
You just need to set the key accordingly.

The way I would really recommend is to create application config variables with a `yaml` file or using `Rails.application.config`

*config/environments/development.rb*

```
config.api_key = "my dev api key"
```

*config/environments/production.rb*

```
config.api_key = "my prod api key"
```

To access your key

```
MyApp::Application.config.api_key
```

Check out this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450285/how-to-define-custom-configuration-variables-in-rails) for other examples.