# How to get domain/subdomains of an app outside of controllers/views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I get the domain and subdomains of my application without being in a controller/view?

The reason for needing this is that I am subscribing to process_action.action_controller notifications within an initializer, and I need my applications' url from within that initializer.

Answer (score 0):

If the host part of the URL (domain, subdomain) is dynamic ... which is to say "depends on the request" then, of course, the only way to get it is within the context of the request itself, which the controllers and views know about.

So I am assuming the application has a known host, perhaps dependent upon runtime environment (production, test, development, etc.), or maybe based on the server environment, but otherwise static.  In this case, you could define a custom config variable containing the name, as noted in the more recent answer from Jack Pratt on this SO question: [How to define custom configuration variables in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450285/how-to-define-custom-configuration-variables-in-rails).