# Configuring variables depending on current Rails.env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What would be the most simple way to configure different variables(for ex. i have variable in tag link_to, which changing, depending on current Rails.env) ?

```
<%
    if Rails.env == 'development'
        domain = 'somedomain.me'
    elsif Rails.env == 'staging'
        domain = 'example.com'
    end 
    %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', root_url(:subdomain => 'www', :domain => domain), :class=>"btn btn-primary"%>
```

I want to move this if - elsif statement to somewhere else, or even drop it for some kind of 'configuration files' if any exists

Comment: Can you update your question with specific examples of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an awesome gem for just this, called `rails_config`: [github repo](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config)

But if you just want to configure this and only this variable, you could create a constant at the environment configuration files that rails already has.

Something like:

In your config/environments/production.rb

```
# production.rb
Rails.configuration.my_awesome_changing_domain = "somedomain.me"
```

In your config/environments/development.rb

```
# development.rb
Rails.configuration.my_awesome_changing_domain = "stackoverflow.com"
```

In your config/environments/staging.rb

```
# staging.rb
Rails.configuration.my_awesome_changing_domain = "news.ycombinator.com"
```

Other methods to do that are discussed in another answers, at this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5053882

Best regards