# Custom rails configuration section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what's the best way to create a custom configuration section for a rails app? ideally i'd like the end result to be an api call like:

```
Rails.configuration.foo.bar
Rails.configuration.foo.baz
```

e.g.

```
Rails.configuration.stackoverflow.api_key
Rails.configuration.stackoverflow.api_secret
```

and i would store the stackoverflow configuration in some .rb file (config/initializers?) and i would obviously have others that are similarly namespaced within `Rails.configuration`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you're looking for is [ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/OrderedOptions.html).

It is used by rails internally to set config namespace. It allows to do something like this, in `config/application.rb` :

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...
    config.foo = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new 
    config.foo.bar = :bar
  end
end
```

You can then retrieve it the usual way :

```
Rails.configuration.foo.bar
```

If you want this to be environment specific, you also can use it in `config/environments/*.rb` rather than `config/application.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4 use [custom-configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration) is better.

```
$ Rails.configuration.x.class
# Rails::Application::Configuration::Custom < Object

Rails.application.configure do    
  # custom configuration section
  config.x.foo.bar = "foo.bar"
end

$ Rails.configuration.x.foo.bar
# "boo.bar"
```