# Making sure my http_basic_authenticate_with password isn't floating around

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, basic-authentication

I wan't to make sure my http_basic_authenticate_with username and password isn't floating around since if i add it to get hub it would be displayed. I thought of doing something similar to this

http_basic_authenticate_with :name => Project.admin_user,
                               :password => Project.admin_password,
                               :only => ['edit', 'destroy', 'new']

```
def self.admin_password
    authentication_file = File.open("/home/mika/Desktop/authentication.txt", "r")
    authentication_file.each_line do |line|
      if  line =~ /\APassword: /
        @password = line[10, line.length - 11 ]
      end
    end
    return @password
  end

  def self.admin_password
    authentication_file = File.open("/home/mika/Desktop/authentication.txt", "r")
    authentication_file.each_line do |line|
      if line =~ /\AUser: /
        @user = line[6, line.length - 7]
      end
    end
    return @user
  end
```

but this requires the authentication.txt. What's the best way I can add this to my website without my username and password floating around (Since its just me using this website its impractical to add a new model just for this no?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend just looking around at how Rails config variables can be set and used

[This quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450285/how-to-define-custom-configuration-variables-in-rails) has a short and sweet example. There are really a million ways to do it, but you just have to pick one and go with it.

Comment: Thanks, this is great ill add as answer when allowed

Comment: The only one issue with this is that rails config variables are still avalible on git

Comment: You just put it in your `.gitignore` and depending on how you deploy, there are different ways to add your rails config variables