# How to add records via environmental variable?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, environment

I need your guidence about environmental vaariable in ruby.

================================================

I have some code that convert version of device intedtifier => device name..
in my code,
path:

> Config-initilizer-android.rb

```
module Android
  @conversion_table_of_model_id_and_device_name = {
    'Anroid2,3'   => 'Gingerbread',
    'Android3,0'   => 'Honeycomb',
    'Android4,1'   => 'ICS',
    'Android4,2'   => 'JB',
}
```

in the future, if there's another name of android eg.'KitKat'. i want to add it using environment variable not use the hard code. 
how can i to do it? is it possible to that?
where should i put it?

regards.
agstwn

Answer (score 1):

With Rails 4.1 you can use `secrets.yml`, check out [this link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml)

If you have earlier version, try [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

Answer (score 1):

What blocks you from using `ENV` constant?

```
module Android
  @conversion_table_of_model_id_and_device_name = {
    'Anroid2,3'   => 'Gingerbread',
    'Android3,0'   => 'Honeycomb',
    'Android4,1'   => 'ICS',
    'Android4,2'   => 'JB',
    'Android4,3'   => ENV[ 'ANDROID_OS_NAME' ]
}
```

Comment: i'm just using it model, when i model. so when i input in database like this `android ( android2,3)` => os ( device model name)

Comment: @agstwn21 I don't understood you, please update the quesion with a code

Comment: sorry,i push 'enter' by accident. 
===============
I'm using a helper and model, 
`Android.conversion_table_of_model_id_and_device_name[model_id]`
and in the model i just call it. 
`device_model_name = Android.convert_model_id_to_device_name(device_model)` 

there's 2 type in ui when input.
1. when i input in device menu, like this android2,3 it will become gingerbread
2.when i input in db, like this android (android2,3) in the ui will become android (gingerbread)

i want to add the records by using environmental variable, i dont need to hard code if the new feature/os has come. @Малъ Скрылевъ

Comment: is it ok if i do this `ENV['MODEL_IDENTTIFIER'] => ENV['DEVICE_NAME']` @446276

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that `ENV` vars are still variables, meaning you can use them in a similar way. I'd propose using something like [the new secrets.yml in Rails 4.1](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4%5f1%5frelease%5fnotes.html#config-secrets-yml), or something like [config spartan](https://github.com/cjbottaro/config%5fspartan) to create a yml structure of the data you need:

```
#config/secrets.yml
development:
  android:
    2.3: "gingerbread"
    3.0: "Honeycomb"
    4.1: "ICS"
    4.2: "JB"
    4.4: "KK"


module Android
    @conversion_table_of_model_id_and_device_name
    me = {}
    Rails.application.secrets.android.each do |k,v|
        me[k.to_sym] = v
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, 
but i'm using rails 3.0.20
i just to add record by using env variable if in future there's a new version of android os @rich-peck

Comment: Okay it's up to you! You have to remember an ENV variable is on the OS -- so if you change hosting providers, etc, your ENV vars will not persist

Comment: ow i see, so when i change my provider the variable will be lost,right? @rick-peck

Comment: is there another way to add records by using env variable, by running in the  console and put the records in the ui and will change to device name i'm a new guy in ruby.. @rich-peck

Comment: There are several options -- you could create an initializer & set your own variables / constants (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450285/how-to-define-custom-configuration-variables-in-rails). You could create data table for them; But I'd recommend [config-spartan](https://github.com/cjbottaro/config_spartan) to store the elements you need