# finding a ruby gem for config settings that can be updated from web interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a rails web app that is a really a content management system. Thus there is going to be a admin section of the app. There I want users to be able to set config setting that are available through the app. Thus I want basic CRUD functionality for config settings. (If you've ever used the admin section of the Discourse discussion board, you'll know what I want to do)

Most of the config gems I have seem to be about organizing config info during development, but seem to expect that config info to be basically set and static on production. (See [How to define custom configuration variables in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450285/how-to-define-custom-configuration-variables-in-rails))

However, in the above link there was one gem called rails-settings (https://github.com/Squeegy/rails-settings) that, in its description, seemed very close to what I want. However, it seems very old (last commit was 2009).

Three related questions:

1) Is there is a standard Gem for this kind of thing that I'm missing?

2) Should I use rails-settings?

3) Should I just create my own model called Settings < ActiveRecord and would this model be available throughout all my controllers?

Comment: Have you tried active admin?

Comment: Looks interesting; also looks a little bit heavy for my present needs