# Rails 4 - how can I use a constant in the /config/environments/production.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, production, staging

In `config/data.yml`, I have:

```
development:
  something: some_value
production:
  something: different_value
```

in `config/initializers/constants.rb`, I load it:

```
CONST_DATA = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/data.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

and then I want to use this `CONST_DATA` in the  `/config/environments/production.rb` file, but when I do that, I get an error saying

```
ERROR -- : uninitialized constant CONST_DATA (NameError)
```

How to make this constant accessible in the `/config/environments/production.rb` file?

Thank you

Comment: The initializers are run only after the environment is set up. But of course you can load your constant explicitly at the top of `production.rb` using e.g. `require 'config/initializers/constants'`.

Comment: Also, including the line with `load_file` directly in your production.rb or application.rb would be fine I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [release of Rails 4.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html) there's a file called `config/secrets.yml`. This data is loaded and available during initialization. You can then access keys in it like this:

```
Rails.application.secrets.key_name
```

Answer (score 0):

[Config](https://github.com/railsconfig/config) gem helps you easily manage environment specific settings in an easy and usable manner.

Following link explains about how to define custom configuration variables in rails:

[How to define custom configuration variables in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450285/how-to-define-custom-configuration-variables-in-rails)