# How to write an XML/YAML file to store application parameters? And how to read that file using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I should decide definitely whether store common parameter for my application in a XML file, in a Yaml file or in the database. Currently, the database is my choice.

What I should make as parameters is something like these:

```
min_name_length
max_name_length
min_surname_length
max_surname_length
...
```

*What is the best choice?*

If the answer is "XML file" or "YAML file" (I think so because these approach saves a lot of database querying and loading), I must create one of those... but how to write an XML/YAML file to store common application parameters? And how to read that file located, for example', in the 'RAILS_ROOT/models' folder using Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several different options here, but it's best to choose between file-based or database.

**Database-stored settings:**

I personally like the database better and use [this rails3 fork](https://github.com/100hz/rails-settings) of [ledderman's rails-settings plugin](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings).

It's quite simple to setup and flexible enough for my uses. You can specify your settings names, default values and it's quite straightforward.

**YAML file-stored settings:**

You have a detailed answer on how to keep settings in an YAML file [right here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app/592593#592593).