# How to set global variables to use everywhere in my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, initialization, global-variables

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to set some global variable to use those everywhere in my application. In particular, the domain name.

If, for example, my website URL is

```
http://subname.domain.com
```

I would like to set or retrieve the `subname.domain.com` value in order to use that in my application like this

```
request_uri = "http://#{sub_domain_name}"
```

**Where and how I have to state\initialize the `sub_domain_name` variable or other variables at all?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to create custom config options for my Rails app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application controller is one place where you can set global variable. Just call a before_filter method in the landing function of the application.

If your question is specific to retrieving domain name of your application, you can use `request.env['HTTP_HOST']`.

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You can add an initialiser in `config/initializers/` where you can declare and set the values of global variables / singletons, which would be available to your app.

Comment: I must declare those like `VARIABLE` or can I use `variable`?