# how to create custom data config to load services host in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a custom config in my app rails to load the configuration url of my services and accessing the configuration in my models.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the file you need in your config directory, for example `my_config.yml` and populate it with the options you require per environment:

```
development:
  debug_enabled: true

test:
  debug_enabled: false

production:
  debug_enabled: false
```

Then create a file called `load_config.rb` in your config/initializers directory with this in it:

```
MY_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/my_config.yml")[Rails.env]
```

Then you can use those settings in your applications like so:

```
if MY_CONFIG[:debug_enabled]
  # ... do something special ...
end
```