# Rails 3 custom yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I want to read variables from yaml file. I tried [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file) but it is not working because I use Rails 3.2. Also I tried [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app) again I saw that it is not working.

How can I read some variables from custom yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the rails [config gem](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config) as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450345/532102).

edit: fot rails 3 you better use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5053882/532102

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with starting server again. However, there was an error again. The path of config file was wrong. I fixed it and everything is working now. I used [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/592593/665123)