# How does one store credentials on the development and production environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security

I read the solution at: [Best way to create custom config options for my Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app) which seems promising. i.e. storing development and production credentials in `config/config.yml`. But then I thought.

If we have a team of developers, and interns, they would be exposed to this file with all production credentials. The consensus, is to trust your team. But honest human mistakes do happen: computer left on / unlocked, trojans, friends using the computer, etc.

I know Heroku has something called [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) + [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman). However, for things like AWS, its not as simple as creating a new access key and delegating that access key to a specific bucket. It doesn't work like that. The only way I can think of is to create a new AWS account solely for development purposes. If I go this route, I would have to create development accounts for other similar 3rd party services too.

Is there an alternative option?

Answer (score 1):

I use [SettingsLogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic).

I create two models for that : Settings and PrivateSettings. And I separate the settings : passwords, token, api key... in PrivateSettings and the rest in Settings.

For Settings :

```
class Settings < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/settings.yml"
  namespace Rails.env
end
```

The `settings.yml` file is stored in Git.

For PrivateSettings :

```
class PrivateSettings < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/private_settings.yml"
  namespace Rails.env
end
```

I store a `private_settings-sample.yml` file in Git, to keep an example in sync. The production data are obvioulsy not populated. A dev clone the repo, and rename it to `private_settings.yml` to be able to work.

`config/private_settings.yml` is also in `.gitignore` to avoid an inclusion by mistake.

Going to prod, I use a specific task in Capistrano to create a symbolic link to the proper `private_settings.yml` file stored in the server (in a dir `config` next to `current`, `releases` and `shared`) :

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :config_settings do
    run "cd #{current_path}/config && ln -sf #{shared_path}/../config/private_settings.yml private_settings.yml"
  end
end
after "deploy:update", "deploy:config_settings"
```

Comment: I don't store yet MyApp::Application.config.secret_token (located in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`) in PrivateSettings. It would be a good practice to not leave this in Git as it secures your cookies.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if you can prevent developers from knowing the password. even if you have completely separated service that provides you the correct credentials/keys, developers can always debug the working application, add code that logs passwords etc. those are people you have to trust. the only way i see it possible is to have admins that puts required keys on the classpath and always do code reviews to prevent all attempts of reading the credentials at runtime