# What is the proper way to handle Oauth Consumer Key and Secret in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security, oauth

I have a Rails application that connects to Facebook using OAuth. I'm looking for is a full description of **how to handle the OAuth key and secret** I get from facebook.

1. Where to store them?
2. How to store them there? I saw an answer saying it should be an env variable, but I'm looking for specifics: How do add them to env? manually? script? what script? where should it be? what about source control? what about production?
3. Any other details that I should know in order to implement the solution in dev, test and production.

I've seen some variants of this question, but never with a complete and detailed answer.

I'm really looking for the overall flow, but also need all the small details that may look trivial but are important to understand this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to store your secret keys and environment-specific configuration outside of your code. You should store these in a way that would allow you to publish your source code in a public repository on, say github, without ignoring any files in source control. This is a principle of the Twelve-Factor Methodology.

Anyway, to answer your question, you could add these keys as shell variables. This assumes you are developing on *nix.

```
$ echo "export OAUTH_SECRET='kie92j8fKEHHE92Va1njk3'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Now in your Rails code, you have access to all your environment variables:

```
ENV["OAUTH_SECRET"]
```

These environment variables can be set in a deploy script that prompts you for them on the command line. This also allows each developer on your team to have his or her own keys.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the people create their own config.yml. It is very easy to do. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app) is a detailed description for creating config.yml

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I'm looking for a more elaborate and specific explanation