# How do i get current file path in a YAML file using ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, erb

In my `config/database.yml` file i need to retrieve the current file path. I've tried this :

```rb
<%
  logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  logger.debug __FILE__
%>
```

That outputs `(erb)` instead of `./config/database.yml`

I know i can get the file path using

```rb
Rails.root.join('config', 'database.yml')
```

But that's just not satisfying as it's not dynamic.

The goal here is to get the unix name of the file owner in order to use it as a prefix to the database name so more than one developer can work with different database without the risk of committing unwanted changes :

```rb
development:
    database: <%= Etc.getpwuid(File.stat(__FILE__).uid).name %>_project_db
```

Comment: @MrYoshiji you can use ruby/erb code in yaml file using `<% %>` and `<%= %>` tags

Comment: Okay @checkit I deleted my (useless) comment, thanks

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app for a better way to have custom environments

Comment: @Crystark Is it giving any error.. Try: `'<%= Etc.getpwuid(File.stat(__FILE__).uid).name %>_project_db'`

Comment: @checkit It raises the following error: `No such file or directory - (erb)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone finds this, here's how i did it in the end:

In **application.rb**

```rb
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.whoami = Etc.getpwuid(File.stat(__FILE__).uid).try(:name)
  config.whoami.try(:downcase!)

  [...]
end
```

And in **database.yaml**

```
development:
  database: <%= Rails.application.config.whoami %>_project_db
```