# How do a config file and generator for my rails gem with yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

How can I do a generator and a config file with `yaml` for my own rails gem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nice documentation in Rails guides on how to create a generator, [Here is the link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#creating-your-first-generator)

Also [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app) that illustrates how to create a config file with yaml