# Configuring Neo4j with rails for different environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, rspec

I have configured Neo4j in development environment using neo4j core gem.

To create a new connection, i have used the below code in application.rb

**Application.rb**

```
neo4j_adaptor = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::Adaptors::HTTP.new('http://localhost:7474')
neo4j_session = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession.new(neo4j_adaptor)
```

How to configure the neo4j so that development environment and test environment uses different database.

eg: for development sample_development and for running rspec sample_test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how much experience you have with Rails. But in rails you mainly have 3 environments be default:

1- development

2- test

3- production

You can have different configs for different environments as shown in this SO question:

[Best way to create custom config options for my Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app)

Last thing, I would not recommend to use the Neo4j adapter directly unless you are really experienced and need direct access to it because of business requirements.

I'd recommend to use Neo4jrb wrapper around the core adapter as shown here:

https://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/9.2.x/Setup.html#generating-a-new-app

---

**UPDATE**

Create a file called `neo4j.yml` inside `config` directory in your project with following code:

```
development:
  neo4j_api: http://localhost:7474

test:
  neo4j_api: http://something_else:7474

production:
  neo4j_api: http://maybe_something_else:7474
```

then create an `initializer` in your project lets call it `neo4j.rb` so its path should be: `config/initializers/neo4j.rb`.

Inside this initializer put the following code:

```
NEO4J_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config/neo4j.yml'))[Rails.env]
```

Then you will have the `NEO4J_CONFIG` accessible at any part of your rails application like:

`NEO4J_CONFIG['neo4j_api']`

and your code should look like:

```
neo4j_adaptor = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::Adaptors::HTTP.new(NEO4J_CONFIG['neo4j_api'])
neo4j_session = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession.new(neo4j_adaptor)
```

Comment: How to use Neo4jrb wrapper for existing rails app? Actually , now  i am  trying to  migrate from postgres to neo4j, for that configurations has to be done on my already existing rails app

Comment: @SuriyaLakshmi have a look on my updated post then :)